# JQuery AutoComplete - Custom Output

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have the following code:

```
$("#search-field").autocomplete({
   appendTo: "#box",
      source: function(request, response){
          $.ajax({
              url: "http://ff.search.yahoo.com/gossip",
              dataType: "jsonp",
              data: {
                  "output": "jsonp",
                  "command": request.term
              },
        success: function(data) {
                  var suggestions = [];

                  $.each(data.gossip.results, function(i, val) {
                      suggestions.push(val.key);
                  });

                  response(suggestions);

              }
          });
      }
  });
```

Basically, when you put in a few letters the autocomplete returns 10 items in the following way:

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
 <a id="ui-id-12" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Returned Text</a>
</li>
```

How would I edit my code so that it outputs the  with a link like the following:

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
 <a href="http://www.searchlotto.co.uk/2012/yhs_search.php?q=RETURNED TEXT&cid=" id="ui-id-12" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Returned Text</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score -2):

After each push you will need to use Jquery to find the anchor tag you inserted and update the href on it

Comment: I'm not outputting the anchor tag. That is part of the JQuery autocomplete function

Comment: @user3215205 - in that case then you are going to have to wire up the response( event, ui ) which is triggered after your search is complete but before the autocomplete shows up on the screen - at that point update the href on each of the anchors that have been added.